# How to filter array of object value and update the values using useState in React JS

Tags: javascript, reactjs, filter, react-hooks

I have a array of object

```
const formFields = {
    firstName: {
        value: '',
        label: 'FirstName',
        type: 'text',
        placeHolder: 'Enter Firstname',
        helperText: '',
        required: false,
        error: false
    },
    lastName: {
        value: '',
        label: 'LastName',
        type: 'text',
        placeHolder: 'Enter LastName',
        helperText: '',
        required: false,
        error: false
    },
    emailID: {
        value: 'sfas',
        label: 'emailID',
        type: 'email',
        placeHolder: 'Enter Email ID',
        helperText: '',
        required: true,
        error: false
    },
    password: {
        value: '',
        label: 'password',
        type: 'password',
        placeHolder: 'Enter password',
        helperText: '',
        required: true,
        error: false
    },
    confirmPassword: {
        value: '',
        label: 'confirmPassword',
        type: 'password',
        placeHolder: 'Enter Confirm Password',
        helperText: '',
        required: true,
        error: false
    }
}

const [inpValues, setInpValues] = useState(formFields)
```

**Filter and Update**

I am trying to filter the object by values where `required === true` and `value.length === 0`

and update the filtered array values like `helperText = "Enter the " + label` and `error = true`

```
const validate = () => {

    const requiredFields = Object.values(inpValues).filter((fields) => {
    if (fields.required === true && fields.value.length === 0) {

            //How to setInpValues

            //setInpValues(...inpValues, fields: { fields.helperText = "Enter the " + fields.label})
            //fields.error = true
        }
    })
}

<MyButton color="primary" handleOnClick={validate} text="SIGN UP"></MyButton>
```

Comment: May I ask why you've choses to set your data an object instead of an array?

Comment: @EmielZuurbier, you mean to apply and filter in `formFields` instead of `inpValues`. I tried it, Actually I filtered and update the values of `formFields`, It works with plain javascript.  but it doesn't render immediately. I have to reload the page to see the reflection

Comment: No I mean that `formFields` is an object, though you need to loop through it and filter stuff out like an array. What is the benefit of doing `formFields = {}` compared to `formFields = [{}, {}]`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The validate function should be, this will also take care of reverting the error back in case of validity.

```js
const validate = () => {
    let newValues={...inpValues}
    const requiredFields = Object.keys(newValues).forEach((key) => {
    let field=newValues[key];
    if (field.required === true && field.value.length === 0) {
            field.helperText=`Enter the ${field.label}`;
            field.error = true;
            newValues[key]= field;
        }else{
           newValues[key].error=false;
           newValues[key].helperText='';
        }
    })
setInpValues(newValues);
}
```

Comment: thanks Bond :). and I understand it too.

Answer (score 0):

The array filter callback function expects you to return a boolean that says if the current value should be filtered out or not. I think something like

```
const validate = () => {

    const requiredFields = Object.values(inpValues).filter((fields) => {
    if (fields.required === true && fields.value.length === 0) {
      return true;
      }
      return false;
    })
    setInpValues(requiredFields)
}
```

this would solve it. In this example you first filter the input values and when they're filtered, you set them to the state. This sets `inputValues` to be all the required fields, every time you click.

Comment: thanks, but you did not update the value any where in your answer

Comment: Which value are you looking to update? 
`setInpValues(requiredFields)` updates the state value every time you click the button. Your initial state is the value of `const formFields` and every time you click you set a new value

Comment: If you'd like to update the helper text, or something else before filtering and setting it to state, you can use something like `.map` before `.filter` to do that. You shouldn't change the values in a filter callback.